# Uploading fixtures to django running within docker container in an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: django, docker, amazon-ec2

So I have a a few operations I need to perform on a running instance - kind of a one-off thing. That involves uploading fixtures to it. The structure is an aws ec2 instance, on which runs a few docker container, including a django container. This the docker container in which I need to upload fixtures. This is all part of a ci/cd pipeline, with a postgres RDS database, nginx proxy, and the django container.

I can scp the fixtures into the AWS EC2 instance. Then I can SSH into the EC2 instance, and from there log into the running container (using docker exec).

That's all fine, but....

**How can I access the fixtures that I uploaded to the ec2 instance (the docker host) from within the docker-container?**

Note: I'm aware I could commit the fixtures to git, then they would find their way into the docker image and be readily available there. I possible I'd rather scp them directly to ec2 & manage them in command lines (because small changes might be needed to the fixtures, which then means I have to run the whole pipeline and wait a few minutes each time...)

Answer (score 1):

You would want to attach a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to your Docker container. By attaching a volume essentially you are sharing a folder from the host machine with the running Docker container.

You can attach a volume when you start the container:

```
docker run -d \
  --name=my-container-name \
  -v  /host/path:/container/path \
  myimage:latest
```

In case of docker compose, you can add a volume like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage
    volumes:
      - "/host/path:/container/path"
```

Comment: Hmm okay, but then....  I'm not going to change the docker-compose command for that. I guess I could stop the running container, restart with with the bind mound, do the business, stop it, then restart it with the production command?

Comment: If you have docker compose it is event more easier. I've updated the answer, also you should check out the official [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose).

Comment: Right - but then it becomes a bit messy to have multiple docker-compose configs, because I would need to add some sort of option to select which one to run in the ci/cd pipeline.... Though I guess I could upload 2 docker-compose file - one real production that always runs, and the one I need for fooling around. Weirdly I hadn't really realized it's pretty much the same as doing this locally. Thanks for the ideas.